# Is it possible to store data in function to an object literal by passing argument to a function?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, javascript-objects

I added my html and js snippet however it still not completed. Sorry if the code is a bit messy this is my first attempt for me to build something like this on my own.

`

```js
var selectBread = document.querySelectorAll(".bread-select");
var sauceSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".sauces-select");
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var orderModal = document.getElementById("order-modal");
let chosenItem;
let chosenItemPrice;
var ingredients = [];
var ingredientsPrice = [];
let selectedItem;
var sideDishes = [];
var drink = [];
var toasted;
var currentSandwich = {};
var breadAndPrice = [
  ["baguette", 0.8],
  ["burger bun", 0.8],
  ["ciabatta", 0.9],
  ["focaccia", 1.5],
  ["ftira", 0.8],
  ["olive bread", 1.3],
  ["rye bread", 1.3],
  ["sliced bread", 0.9],
  ["tortilla", 1.6],
  ["wheat bread", 0.9],
  ["whole grain bread", 1.2]
];
var sauceAndPrice = [
  ["chili sauce", 0.25],
  ["garlic and olive oil", 0.35],
  ["ketchup", 0.15],
  ["mayonnaisee", 0.15],
  ["garlic basil mayo", 0.45],
  ["mustard", 0.25]
];

function getBreadInfo(el, currentOption) {
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    //add event listener to all bread select menu options
    el[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
      selectedItem = event.target.value; //current selected item
      getArrIndex(currentOption, selectedItem);
      if (event.target.name === "bread-select") {
        currentSandwich.breadType = chosenItem;
        currentSandwich.breadPrice = chosenItemPrice;
      } else if (event.target.name === "sauce-select") {
        currentSandwich.sauce = chosenItem;
        currentSandwich.saucePrice = chosenItemPrice;
      } else if (event.target.name === "side-dishes-select") {
        currentSandwich.sideDish = chosenItem;
        currentSandwich.sideDishPrice = chosenItemPrice;
      } else if (event.target.name === "drinks-select") {
        currentSandwich.drinkSelect = chosenItem;
        currentSandwich.drinkPrice = chosenItemPrice;
      } else if (event.target.name === "toasted-select") {
        currentSandwich.toasted = chosenItem;
      }
    });
  }
}

function getArrIndex(arr, val) {
  // val is the selected item
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //iterate through the current choosen array
    if (arr[i][0] === val) {
      // when selected item is found in the array
      chosenItem = arr[i][0]; // store the item in choosenItem value
      chosenItemPrice = arr[i][1]; // store the item price in choosenItem value
    }
  }
}
getBreadInfo(selectBread, breadAndPrice);
getBreadInfo(sauceSelect, sauceAndPrice);
//get the index of the selected item from the bread and price array

function getIngredientsInfo() {
  for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    //loop check boxes
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
      //add event listener to check boxes
      if (event.target.checked) {
        //check if check boxes are checked
        ingredients.push(event.target.name); //push the name of ingredient to ingredients array
        ingredientsPrice.push(event.target.value); //get the price of the item checked from value attr and push it to ingredientsPrice array
      } else if (event.target.checked === false) {
        var index = ingredients.indexOf(event.target.name);
        ingredients.splice(index, 1);
        ingredientsPrice.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }
}
getIngredientsInfo();
```

```html
<section class="order-section">
  <h2 class="selection-header">Choose your...</h2>
  <div class="select-container">

    <select class="bread-select" name="bread-select">
      <option selected disabled>Bread Type</option>
      <option value="baguette">Baguette</option>
      <option value="burger bun">Burger Bun</option>
      <option value="ciabatta">Ciabatta</option>
      <option value="focaccia">Focaccia</option>
      <option value="ftira">Ftira</option>
      <option value="olive bread">Olive Bread</option>
      <option value="rye bread">Rye Bread</option>
      <option value="sliced bread">Sliced Bread</option>
      <option value="tortilla">Tortilla</option>
      <option value="wheat bread">Wheat Bread</option>
      <option value="whole grain bread">Whole Grain Bread</option>
    </select>


    <select class="sauces-select" name="sauce-select">
      <option selected disabled>Sauces</option>
      <option value="chili sauce">Chili Sauce</option>
      <option value="garlic and olive oil">Garlic and Olive Oil</option>
      <option value="ketchup">Ketchup</option>
      <option value="mayonnaise">Mayonnaise</option>
      <option value="garlic basil mayo">Garlic Basil Mayo</option>
      <option value="mustard">Mustard</option>
    </select>

    <select class="side-dishes-select" name="side-dishes-select">
      <option selected disabled>Side Dishes</option>
      <option value="coleslaw">Coleslaw</option>
      <option value="curly fries">Curly Fries</option>
      <option value="mixed salad">Mixed Salad</option>
      <option value="potato wedges">Potato Wedges</option>
      <option value="potatoes salad">Potatoes Salad</option>
      <option value="sliced Potatoes fries">Sliced Potatoes Fries</option>
      <option value="sweet potatoes fries">Sweet Potatoes Fries</option>
    </select>

    <select class="drinks-select" name="drinks-select">
      <option selected disabled>Drinks</option>
      <option value="Still Water">Still Water</option>
      <option value="Fizzy Water">Fizzy Water</option>
      <option value="coca cola">Coca Cola</option>
      <option value="sprite">Sprite</option>
      <option value="fanta">Fanta</option>
      <option value="kinnie">Kinnie</option>
      <option value="cisk">Cisk</option>
    </select>

    <select class="toasted-select" name="toasted-select">
      <option selected disabled>Toasted</option>
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</section>
```

`I have a function which I am using to get data from select menus and I would like to save the data to an object by passing it as an argument. At the moment the only solution I found is to use if statements but it look bad. Any help to refactor this please?

```
      if (event.target.name === "bread-select") {
    currentSandwich.breadType = chosenItem;
    currentSandwich.breadPrice = chosenItemPrice;
  } else if (event.target.name === "sauce-select") {
    currentSandwich.sauce = chosenItem;
    currentSandwich.saucePrice = chosenItemPrice;
  } else if (event.target.name === "side-dishes-select") {
    currentSandwich.sideDish = chosenItem;
    currentSandwich.sideDishPrice = chosenItemPrice;
  } else if (event.target.name === "drinks-select") {
    currentSandwich.drinkSelect = chosenItem;
    currentSandwich.drinkPrice = chosenItemPrice;
  } else if (event.target.name === "toasted-select") {
    currentSandwich.toasted = chosenItem;
  }
```

Comment: do you have control of the name of the selects?

Comment: What do you mean by "*by passing it as an argument*"?

Comment: Something like this:

``function foo(obj){
currentSandwich.obj = chosenItem;
}

foo(breadType);
``
I know this will not work but to try to explain myself better what I really mean.

Comment: This snippet of code doesn't contain enough information on what you're trying to do.  If it's part of a function, could you show more of it, including the parameters and the return?

Comment: I don't think there is any refactoring possible here. Except a switch statement, but that doesn't make it more pretty.

Comment: @CodeHacker.  Sure there are possible refactorings.  How about something that used `{'bread-select': 'breadType|breadPrice', 'sauce-select': 'sauce|saucePrice', ..., 'toasted-select': 'toasted'}` paired with a generic function that handled that format?  Not that this is definitely worth doing, but it might be if there are enough choices.

Comment: Well, that edit was a lot more than I was looking for, but still it should help.

Comment: Could you put the prices inside the HTML to clean things up?  `<option value="baguette" data-price="0.8">Baguette</option>` Or in an object with keys matching your `select` names?  `{'bread-select': {'baguette': 0.8, ...}, 'sauces-select': {'chili sauce': 0.25, ...}, ...}`

Comment: @ScottSauyet: What I meant to say: There is no refactoring worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the switch is the way to go, it is both faster and better practice.

```
switch(event.target.name) {
  case 'bread-select':
    currentSandwich.breadType = chosenItem;
    currentSandwich.breadPrice = chosenItemPrice;
    break;
  ...
  default:
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's faster? Also it's still repetitive.

Comment: Thanks this looks better however I prefer if it can get cleaner. Sorry I could not thumb up your message I still have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: Although he has different keys for each case. So I do not see passing as an argument would work.
Also, I feel a switch case eliminates redundant code like comparing name repeatedly and even the code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string to make a property assignment to and object using `[]` bracket notation. So if you are able to get a relevant property name, or part of a property name from your selects, that should work for you.

```js
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
  selects[i].addEventListener('change', selectHandler);
}
var currentSandwich = {};
var prices = {
  soda : .5,
  tea : .5,
  lemonade : 1,
  water : 0,
  corn : 2,
  potatoes : 2.5,
  carrots : 1.5
};

function selectHandler(evt){
  var name = evt.target.name;
  var selection = evt.target.value;
  currentSandwich[name] = selection;
  if(prices[selection]){
    currentSandwich[name+"price"] = prices[selection];
  }else{
    currentSandwich[name+"price"] = 0;
  }
  console.log(currentSandwich);
}
```

```html
<select name='drink'>
  <option value=''>Please Choose One</option>
  <option value='soda'>Soda</option>
  <option value='tea'>Tea</option>
  <option value='lemonade'>Lemonade</option>
  <option value='water'>Water</option>
</select>
<select name='side'>
  <option value=''>Please Choose One</option>
  <option value='corn'>Corn</option>
  <option value='potatoes'>Potatoes</option>
  <option value='carrots'>Carrots</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks this is deffinetly cleaner I wish I can get solutions this  fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is a significantly different approach. It stores prices and some keys in the HTML markup, and uses a simple function to use these to update your sandwich.

I don't know if this sort of refactoring is what you were looking for, but it's one reasonable way to avoid such repetitive logic.

```js
var sandwich = {};
var sandwichContainer = document.getElementById('sandwich-options');
sandwichContainer.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
  var select = event.target;
  var choice = select.selectedOptions[0];
  var choiceName = select.dataset.choiceName;
  sandwich[choiceName] = choice.value
  var priceName = select.dataset.choicePrice;
  if (priceName) {
    sandwich[priceName] = Number(choice.dataset.price);
  }
  console.log(sandwich)
});
```

```html
<section class="order-section">
  <h2 class="selection-header">Choose your...</h2>
  <div id="sandwich-options">

    <select class="bread-select" name="bread-select" 
            data-choice-name="breadType" data-choice-price="breadPrice">
      <option selected disabled>Bread Type</option>
      <option value="baguette" data-price="0.8">Baguette</option>
      <option value="burger bun" data-price="0.8">Burger Bun</option>
      <option value="ciabatta" data-price="0.9">Ciabatta</option>
      <option value="focaccia" data-price="1.5">Focaccia</option>
      <option value="ftira" data-price="0.8">Ftira</option>
      <option value="olive bread" data-price="1.3">Olive Bread</option>
      <option value="rye bread" data-price="1.3">Rye Bread</option>
      <option value="sliced bread" data-price="0.9">Sliced Bread</option>
      <option value="tortilla" data-price="1.6">Tortilla</option>
      <option value="wheat bread" data-price="0.9">Wheat Bread</option>
      <option value="whole grain bread" data-price="1.2">Whole Grain Bread</option>
    </select>


    <select class="sauces-select" name="sauce-select" data-
            choice-name="sauce", data-choice-price="saucePrice">
      <option selected disabled>Sauces</option>
      <option value="chili sauce" data-price="0.25">Chili Sauce</option>
      <option value="garlic and olive oil" data-price="0.35">Garlic and Olive Oil</option>
      <option value="ketchup" data-price="0.15">Ketchup</option>
      <option value="mayonnaise" data-price="0.15">Mayonnaise</option>
      <option value="garlic basil mayo" data-price="0.45"
          >Garlic Basil Mayo</option>
      <option value="mustard" data-price="0.25">Mustard</option>
    </select>

    <select class="toasted-select" name="toasted-select" data-choice-name="toasted">
      <option selected disabled>Toasted</option>
      <option value="yes" data-price="0">Yes</option>
      <option value="no" data-price="0">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</section>
```

An alternate approach would be to store all your prices in a object keyed by the select names, something like this:

```
var prices = {
  'bread-select': {
    'baguette': 0.8, 
    ...
   }, 
   'sauces-select': {
     'chili sauce': 0.25, 
     ...
    }, 
    ...
};
```

and then use `select.name` and `choice.value` from the above to key into this object.  You would also need another object, or a way to enhance this one to store the final property names.